# Uploading multiple file to server: getting PHP code wrong

Tags: php, html

I have the following HTML and PHP codes to handle uploading of multiple files to a folder in a server.
Only one file (from selected upload files) gets uploaded to the server. 
Could someone please advise me on what I am doing wrong? I am just starting PHP/HTML and am clueless with this task.

HTML:

```html
<form action="upload_multi15_action.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select files to upload: <br />
        <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
        <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br /> 
        <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
        <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br /> 
        <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
        <input name="userfile[]" type="file" /><br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload files">


</form>
```

PHP:

```html
    $count=0;

    echo '<pre>';
    foreach($_FILES['userfile']['name'] as $to_upload){    
        $upload = "./".basename($to_upload);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$count], $upload) or       
            die("Possible file upload attack!\n");
        $count = $count++;
        $upload = '';
    }
    print "</pre>";
```

I am totally lost on what I could be doing wrong with the PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$count = $count++;
```

As it's written here, I expect that this will always be 0.  The post-increment operator returns the value and then increments it. But you assign that returned value back to the same variable.  So the next time it tries to move the uploaded file, it no longer exists because you've already moved the first file.

You don't really need to keep a counter this way anyway, you can foreach to give you the index, as I've done here.

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
foreach($_FILES['userfile']['name'] as $count => $to_upload){ 
    if($_FILES['userfile']['error'][$count] != 0) {
        echo "Error {$_FILES['userfile']['error'][$count]} on $count<br>";
        continue;
    }
    $upload = "./".basename($to_upload);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$count], $upload) or       
        die("Possible file upload attack!\n");
    $upload = '';
}
print "</pre>";
```

As a side note, you should probably be checking the incoming names.  For example: as it's written someone can replace your upload file with their own by uploading a PHP file with the same name.  [Edit] It's also generally a good idea to check the incoming data too if you're expecting the files to be a specific kind of file.  Making sure a file can be parsed by `getimagesize` if you're expecting image files, for instance.

---

Alternatively, if you didn't want to use the index from `foreach` and wanted to keep your increment-based method, just change `$count = $count++;` to `$count++;`  This removes the assignment of the post-increment return value back to the `$count` variable, which was causing `$count` to never change.

Comment: I have taken note of your advice. I have quite a lot to learn it seems

Comment: Everyone starts somewhere.  A good rule of thumb is: Never trust the user and validate everything they give you.  Technically, I probably shouldn't even `echo` the `$count` variable like I did there as the user could edit the form and change that too, though I'm having trouble thinking of a useful attack that would exploit that.  BTW, if you didn't want to use the index from foreach and wanted to keep your increment-based method, just change `$count = $count++;` to `$count++;`

Comment: update @EPB, I changed "$count = $count++" to "$count++". This seems to get all the selected files to upload to the server. I am glad but surprised that this small change gets the PHP code to work. Many thanks for your advice.

Comment: No problem, I'll go ahead and edit my answer to include that note in the answer should anyone using the same method stumble upon this.

Answer (score 1):

change this `foreach($_FILES['userfile']['name'] as $to_upload){`

to `foreach($_FILES['userfile']['name'] as $key => $to_upload){`

and then use $key like this

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'][$key], $upload)
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Feroz. It seems that changing the counter in my code as per @EPB's advice is one solution to my problem.